# Android : rotation in textview adds margin on left

Tags: android, rotation, textview

I have used rotation:-90 in xml to rotate the text vertical. But its adding margin on left, I want textview on left side of screen without margin.[image]

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNetworkStatus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:background="@color/completed"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:rotation="-90"
            android:text="Online"
            android:translationZ="1dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your layout xml?

Comment: try to add android:layout_marginTop="-2dp" or left and remove padding

Comment: @Pravin, android:layout_marginLeft="-2dp" worked perfectly!!! thanks..

Comment: @Jignesh wc but check this for all devices